# Multiple values in one cell

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have data looking somewhat similar to this:

```
number    type    results
1         5       x, y, z
2         6       a
3         8       x
1         5       x, y
```

Basically, I have data in Excel that has commas in a couple of individual cells and I need to count each value that is separated by a comma, after a certain requirement is met by subsetting.

Question: How do I go about receiving the sum of 5 when subsetting the data with number == 1 and type == 5, in R?

Comment: How are you storing this data in r? Can you provide a sample dataset in r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `filter` function can filter the rows based on conditions. `separate_rows` can separate the comma. `group_by` is to group the data. `tally` can count the numbers.

```
dt2 <- dt %>%
  filter(number == 1, type == 5) %>%
  separate_rows(results) %>%
  group_by(results) %>%
  tally()
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   results     n
#     <chr> <int>
# 1       x     2
# 2       y     2
# 3       z     1
```

Or you can use `count(results)` only as the following code shows.

```
dt2 <- dt %>%
  filter(number == 1, type == 5) %>%
  separate_rows(results) %>%
  count(results)
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "number    type    results
1         5       'x, y, z'
                 2         6       a
                 3         8       x
                 1         5       'x, y'",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: After `separate_rows(results)`, you can finish with `count(results)` only.

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks for your comment. I have added your suggestion to my code to make the answer more comprehensive.

Comment: Pleasure to help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

If we need the total count, then another option is `str_count` after subsetting

```
library(stringr)
with(df, sum(str_count(results[number==1 & type==5], "[a-z]"), na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 5
```

---

Or with `gregexpr` from `base R`

```
with(df, sum(lengths(gregexpr("[a-z]", results[number==1 & type==5])), na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 5
```

If there are no matching pattern for an element, use

```
with(df, sum(unlist(lapply(gregexpr("[a-z]", 
         results[number==1 & type==5]), `>`, 0)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Or stri_count() in the stringi package will do, I think.

Comment: @jazzurro yes, it will do too.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using base R.   You split `results` on the commas and get the length of each list,  then add these up grouping by `number`.

```
aggregate(sapply(strsplit(df$results, ","), length), list(df$number), sum)
  Group.1 x
1       1 5
2       2 1
3       3 1
```

Your data:

```
df = read.table(text="number    type    results
1         5       'x, y, z'
2         6       'a'
3         8       'x'
1         5       'x, y'",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```